# Roles available with Windows Authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, windows-authentication

I'm trying to add Roles authentication to an Action in a Controller in an ASP.NET MVC application. The code looks something like this:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "SomeRoleName")]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    bool inRole = User.IsInRole("Admin");
```

If I remove the Authorize attribute and put a breakpoint on the last line in that code sample, is there a way that I can inspect the objects and find out what roles are available?

e.g. I call User.IsInRole("Admin) in the Immediate window and it will give me a true/false value. How can I access the collection of roles available?

Comment: Can you clarify your question as to whether you're looking for the roles assigned to the current user or all possible roles that a user could belong to?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you don't need to do this programatically, but you are trying to determine the correct Windows Groups/Roles that need to be specified, you can use this from the command line:

```
C:\> net group /domain  (lists all Roles in the domain)
C:\> net user <username> /domain (lists info, including roles for a user)
```

Otherwise you will need to query the LDAP part of Active Directory, or use something under DirectoryServices.

Take a look at these websites to access Active Directory via C#:

- [Howto: (Almost) Everything In Active Directory via C# - Codeproject](http://en.csharp-online.net/User_Management_with_Active_Directory)
- [User Management with Active Directory](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/everythingInAD.aspx)

Comment: Well, the howto link takes me to 'Chinese dates' now.

Comment: In case someone else wanders in here. The link for "Howto: (Almost) Everything In Active Directory via C# - Codeproject" is: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18102/Howto-Almost-Everything-In-Active-Directory-via-C

Answer (score 8):

Add this to your web.config under system.web:

```
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider"/>
```

Then you can use:

```
string[] arr = Roles.GetRolesForUser(User.Identity.Name);
```

or:

```
string[] arr = Roles.GetRolesForUser();
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, this gives all local and domain roles very fast , for example BUILTIN\\Administrators  group too

Answer (score 3):

You can use the various methods on the RoleProvider class in System.Web.Security.Roles.Provider.

See this for more: [Role Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roleprovider.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you aren't using a role provider here, but falling back on the underlying functionality of WindowsPrincipal where the roles map to the user's groups. Anyhow, I don't think one can do more than enumerate the windows groups available on that machine/in that domain. Not sure if this helps, but that's all I can say without having an idea of what you are trying to do with said roles list.