# Authenticate Workgroup users through Active Directory in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, active-directory, directoryservices, windows-server-2019

I have a Workgroup server that is running IIS with an app that connects to Active directory from another server to authenticate a username and password. I am able to get users from the active directory, but I am unable to authenticate the local users from the workgroup server which is a computer account on the domain controller. How do I check the local users for a non domain joined computer account through Active Directory? Here is my code so far:

```
 private bool CheckDomainUsers(DomainModel model)
    {

        try
        {

        DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + model.Domain);
        DirectorySearcher ds = null;
        de.Username = model.User;
        de.Password = model.Password;
        SearchResult sr;

        
        ds = BuildUserSearcher(de);
      
        ds.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=User)(objectClass=person)(name=" + model.User + "))";

        sr = ds.FindOne();


        return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }


    }
```

If there is some other Windows server or Active Directory concept that I'm missing, feel free to inform me

Comment: This article helped me a while back. There I could query the windows user and its roles. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922378/roles-available-with-windows-authentication

Comment: ...in my case the answer from @lman helped. I ended up using this line: string[] arr = Roles.GetRolesForUser("NameOfUser");

Comment: But that doesen't anwser the question how to authenticate them through Active Directory that is on another server

Comment: aaa yes, I see. Sorry I misunderstood